# Find the top hashtags in the IRA troll tweets dataset?

Tags: twitter, google-bigquery, opendata

Twitter just released millions of tweets associated to the Internet troll farm "Internet Research Agency" (IRA).

> These large datasets comprise 3,841 accounts affiliated with the IRA, originating in Russia, and 770 other accounts, potentially originating in Iran. They include more than 10 million Tweets and more than 2 million images, GIFs, videos, and Periscope broadcasts, including the earliest on-Twitter activity from accounts connected with these campaigns, dating back to 2009.

- https://blog.twitter.com/official/en_us/topics/company/2018/enabling-further-research-of-information-operations-on-twitter.html

Is the dataset available in BigQuery? How can I find the top hashtags?

Answer (score 1):

The investigator Josh Russell shared the dataset released by Twitter in BigQuery - now you can write queries over it.

- https://twitter.com/josh_emerson/status/1052898547182522371

Top tweets by number of retweets their hashtags got (in English):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT hashtag, SUM(retweets) total_retweets
  , ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(retweets, tweet_text) ORDER BY retweets DESC LIMIT 1) top_tweet
FROM (
  SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(tweet_text, r'(?i)#[^ ,:\.\";\!]*') hashtags, tweet_text, retweet_count retweets 
  FROM `reddit-198411.IRAhashed.IRAhashed` a 
  WHERE tweet_language  = 'en'
), UNNEST(hashtags) hashtag
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(hashtags)>0
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

[image]

For other languages I exported the results to a Google Sheet and ran the GOOGLETRANSLATE() function:

```
SELECT hashtag, retweets, top_tweet.*
FROM (
  SELECT hashtag, SUM(retweet_count) retweets
    , ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(retweet_count AS top_rt_count, tweet_language AS lang, tweet_text AS top_tweet) ORDER BY retweet_count DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] top_tweet
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(hashtags, r'.(.*).$'), ', ') hashtags
      , retweet_count, tweet_text, tweet_language   
    FROM `reddit-198411.IRAhashed.IRAhashed` 
    WHERE LENGTH(hashtags)>2
    AND tweet_language NOT IN ('en', 'und')
  ), UNNEST(hashtags) hashtag
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 2 DESC
  LIMIT 500
)
```

[image]

I left other queries on [/r/bigquery](http://reddit.com/r/bigquery):

- https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/9qlyvo/tweet_dataset_tweets_released_by_twitter_russian/